# NodeJS asynchronous process.on with multiple functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, sigint

I have a main function/file which calls a doLogic function/file. This doLogic opens up a database connection, and I am trying to use process.on('SIGINT') to cleanup the database, however, when I hit CTRL-C the process doesn't wait for the asynchronous calls.

main.js

```
import {doLogic} from "./doLogic"
import {cleanup} from "./cleanup"

// Attach SIGINT listener
process.on("SIGINT", async () => {
   await cleanup()
   process.exit(0)
})

async function run() {
  doLogic()
}

run()
```

doLogic.js

```
import { connectionIds } from "./cleanup"

export async function doLogic {
  for (const desiredConnection of desiredConnections) {
      let id = await connectToDB(desiredConnection)
      connectionIds.add(id)
  }
}
```

cleanup.js

```
export const connectionIds = new Map()

// This function is just to simulate disconnecting
unlockConnection(connectionId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("resolve");
    }, 5* 1000);
    setTimeout(() => {
      reject("reject");
    }, 5 * 1000);
  });
}

export async function cleanup() {
   let asyncCalls = []
   for(const lockedConnection of connectionIds.keys()) {
       // I have also tried below with await unlockConn
       // But not much difference
       asyncCalls.push(unlockConnection(lockedConnection))
   }
   return Promise.all(asyncCalls)
}
```

The weird thing is that it is strictly doLogic() which seems to prevent the await cleanup() call from actually awaiting. If I comment this out and just pause the program with stdin() then if I send a SIGINT await cleanup() seems to work fine. Also I can confirm that there are actually connections in the map.

Comment: So, `process.on("SIGINT")` is not promise-aware so it does NOT wait until your `async` callback is done.  There's nothing you can do to work around that.  That's how it is designed.

Comment: Also, if you want to know when `cleanup()` is actually done with everything, you need to use `Promise.allSettled()` not `Promise.all()` because with `Promise.all()` it will reject as soon as the first promise rejects whereas `Promise.allSettled()` will wait for for everything to finish regardless of resolve or reject.  But your simulated `unlockConnection()` will always resolve before the two timers set for the same time will fire in the order they are registered so the `resolve()` timer will always run first.  A better simulation might use a random time for each timer.

Comment: I see, so despite the Promise.all(), there is no way to ensure the async cleanup() completes before the program exits. In other words, cleanup is being called, but then the whole process exits before there is any guarantee cleanup() has done any of its cleaning as Process.on can't account for await?

Comment: Some of this signal processing is platform specific.  On Windows, it appears that `await cleanup()` could work if you convert to `Promise.allSettled()` (works for me in a test app).  I don't know about other platforms.

Comment: What are you actually attempting to do in your real `cleanup()` function?  Open sockets will be closed automatically when the process exits.

Comment: In reality I am trying to execute some database entries, e.g Mark tasks that were marked as “processing” in the start of the program as “processed” if the user terminates the whole program early.

Comment: What platform are you running it on?

Comment: I’m testing it on Mac right now.